# Boost::Variant or Boost::Any instead of serializing

Tags: c++, boost, variant

I have a situation when I need to pass structures of different type from bottom component to higher component (through many more). The interface should be general, e.g. a method 'notify' or similar, and I need to use it with types A, B, C and D. 
For example:

```
notify(A());
notify(b);
notify(otherObject->getC());
notify(d);
```

There will be possibly many more of object types so I don't want to have overloaded 'notify' for every type of notification object.

I think I could use either some serialization mechanism in the bottom component and then unserialize the object in the higher component. However, it will costs some performance. 
What about a boost Variant? Together with the object in the 'notify' method I can send enum specifying type of object, so that the higher component knows what type is in the variant and be able to unpack it.

What do you think?

Or is there a better approach?

Comment: This is exactly what `boost::variant` is designed for. What you have is in reality a function with a single `notify` function that takes a value that is of a compound type that is "values of type A or B or C or D".

Comment: Thanks. I thought so also.

Comment: The drawback is that this design quickly becomes untestable, due to the problem with comparing boost::any. I cannot write a gtest test case and check if correct argument or return value is used.